# Autoindent in Texmaker?

Tags: texmaker, editors

I've been using Texmaker for ~5 years now and prefer it over other editors because of its flexibility.

Is there a way to auto-indent LaTeX code in TeXmaker so that the code becomes more manageable ?

Comment: one such code beautification tool is [latexindent](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexindent/documentation/manual.pdf) by [cmhughes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes) which can be integrated into TeXmaker by `user command`  and automated by [arara](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf). As such TeXmaker does not have any full pledged indentation(i suppose).

Comment: BTW Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @texenthusiast Good idea, but I would be a little concerned that TeXmaker may have some sort of write-protection on the file in question.

Comment: @SeanAllred Although I did not try this personally, but I hope: Options-->Configure-->Editor-->tick on `check for external changes` might work.

Comment: I always had trouble, getting the suggestion of @texenthusiast to work in TeXStudio under Linux. Is there any recent development in 2016?

Comment: What should the line in ```Edit User Command``` for ```latexindent``` look like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upvoted comment converted to answer to clear off the Q from unanswered list.

Such indentation and code beautification is made possible with [latexindent](https://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexindent/documentation/latexindent.pdf) tool by [cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes) which can be integrated into TeXmaker by user command and automated by [arara](https://mirrors.ctan.org/support/arara/doc/arara-manual.pdf). As such TeXmaker does not have any full pledged indentation.

Also one might need to change settings of TeXmaker to notice the indentation changes done by `arara` and `latexindent` externally as shown below

Open TeXmaker: `Options`-->`Configure`-->`Editor`-->tick on `check for external changes` might be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! A quick how-to would be useful though. There's gotta be a quicker, more stackexchange-ish way to explain than linking to a 19-page manual and a 137-page manual.

Comment: Anyone down to try this?

Answer (score 6):

This answer should provide you with two options to quickly indent your `.tex` file without the need to read both manuals.

`arara` manual: [Link](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf)
`latexindent` manual: [Link](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/support/latexindent/documentation/manual.pdf)

## Option 1: Semi-Automated way with file-reload

Using `latexindent` from command line perfectly indents your .tex file. If you use `latexindent -w yourfile.tex` and then click `File -> Reload document from file` your .tex file is indented.

`latexindent` itself is shipped with your Tex* installation. 
If you get `perl` warnings when typing `latexindent -version` using the command line, such should be solved using

```
cpan
install YAML::Tiny
install Getopt::Long
install File::HomeDir
q
```

Credit: [How to configure TexLive 2015 to use latexindent.pl script with Kile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269505/how-to-configure-texlive-2015-to-use-latexindent-pl-script-with-kile)

## Option 2: Automated way using 'arara' (Recommended)

`arara` is also shipped with your Tex* installation.

#### What is `arara`?

Basically it just automates various LaTeX calls. In `Texmaker` you can just set up a custom command in `Users -> own commands`. The command should be `arara %.tex`. This will apply arara on all your `.tex` files in side your directory.

What `arara` will do with the `.tex` file can then be specified inside the file. For me, I need to compile my file with 2x `XeLaTex`, 1x `Biber` (for `bibtex`) and again 1x `XeLaTeX`. Subsequently, I added the following lines into my `.tex` file:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex
```

Then you just execute your custom command in Texmaker and your file will compile as you want.

To check if `arara` is correctly installed on your system just type `arara` in your command line and you should see some overview options.

#### arara and latexindent

`latexindent` can also be called from `arara` inside your `.tex` file every time you compile it. 
To combine the two, follow this guide: [How to configure TexLive 2015 to use latexindent.pl script with Kile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269505/how-to-configure-texlive-2015-to-use-latexindent-pl-script-with-kile)

**Edit [11/2017]**: `arara` v4 comes with an 'indent' rule which is using `latexindent` in the background. There is no installer yet but you can compile v4 easily by following the instructions in the [README](https://github.com/cereda/arara).

You can then just add `% arara: indent: {some.options.here}` to your .tex file.
I currently use `% arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}`.
This rule overwrites your `.tex` file with the indented version created by `latexindent` and (optionally) saves a backup. 
See section 3.2 from the `latexindent` [manual](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/support/latexindent/documentation/manual.pdf) for the options.

**NOTES:**

- However, this way still ends up with compile errors for me using Texmaker. Running `arara` from command line works fine with `latexindent`. Subsequently I suggest to use option 1 or to run `arara` from command line (my current approach) until I figured out what is causing the error using Texmaker.
- <strike>`latexindent` (Version 2.1R) was not updated since two years when writing this answer (https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl) and is causing several `perl` related syntax warnings (`Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex`) when being executed from command line. They do not seem affect its usage and the package maintainer said that these are already fixed in the dev version (2.2R). You can get it from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/develop/latexindent.pl). `latexindent` version 3 is in preparation.</strike>
- [`latexindent`](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl) is currently at version 3.3 and running smoothly. Happy indenting :) [**11/2017**]

Comment: Thanks for this :) version 3.0 was released at the end of Feb 2017, perhaps you could update your answer? :)

Comment: @cmhughes Any changelog for v3.0? Besides the second note that was already addressed in v2.2 dev. Could not find the changelog in your repo. Happy to update my answer then!

Comment: Sure, no problem :) see https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/pull/56 and https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/commits/master. Let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Could this answer be updated with what to do for the perl.exe error for a windows machine?

Comment: @cmhughes I finally updated my answer :)

Comment: @AustinDowney sorry just seeing this now. Feel free to join our [Gitter chat](https://gitter.im/cereda/arara?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge) and we can help you solving the problem :)

Answer (score 6):

I would like to suggest a slight modification of Option 1) by pat-s.

At least in TeXstudio, under

> Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Build

you have the option to add a "User Command". Define a command `latexindent -w %.tex`. Save and return to your document, you can now click on

> Tools -> User -> Your Command

This can also be called via shortcut, i.e. I use `alt + shift + F1` to autoindent the complete document.

Comment: This was incredibly easy to do and worked first time! It took longer than expected and I questioned if I set it up correctly, so be warned that it may take a moment.

Comment: In OSX, the menu is in Preferences -> Build

I'm unable to get the command to run on OSX

Comment: Any pictures given would be helpful.