# arara with indent.yaml works in command line but not in TeXmaker

Tags: texmaker, arara, latexindent

I am running Windows 7 and a recent (Dec 2014) distribution of TeX Live and a recent version of TeXmaker.

When invoking `arara myFile.tex` in the command line it returns "indent SUCCESS" and when opening `myFile.tex` it is indeed beautified/correctly indented.

However when setting up a macro in TeXmaker (via Users->Commands->User-defined "arara %.tex") TeXmaker returns:

> Process started
>
> Process exited normally

However the code is not beautified. Closing and opening the file does not help.

Do you have any ideas on how to make this work?

PS a minimal working example (working from command line - but not via TeXmaker) is:

```
% arara: indent
% arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
        \item a
    \item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

PPS indent.log file output (when invoking via TeXmaker)

> Thu Dec 11 15:41:00 2014
>
> latexindent.pl version 2.0R, a script to indent .tex files
>
> latexindent.pl lives here: C:/texlive/2014/bin/win32/

>

> Directory for backup files and indent.log: .
>
> file: tikpkzTEST.tex
>   Reading defaultSettings.yaml from C:/texlive/2014/bin/win32/defaultSettings.yaml
>
> Home directory is C:/Users/Björn
>   To specify user settings you would put indentconfig.yaml here: 
>     C:/Users/Björn/indentconfig.yaml
>
> Backup procedure:
>      (...various backups...)
>      Overwriting file: tikpkzTEST.tex
>
> Line Count of tikpkzTEST.tex: 10
>   Line Count of indented tikpkzTEST.tex: 10
>
> Line counts of original file and indented file match

PPPS arara.log file

> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:09.524 INFO  Arara - Welcome to arara!
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:09.524 INFO  Arara - Processing file 'tikpkzTEST.tex', please wait.
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:09.524 INFO  DirectiveExtractor - Reading directives from
>
> tikpkzTEST.tex.
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:09.524 TRACE DirectiveExtractor - Directive found in line 1 with 
>   indent.
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:09.524 TRACE DirectiveExtractor - Directive found in line 2 with 
>   indent: {overwrite: yes}.
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:09.584 INFO  DirectiveParser - Parsing directives.
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:09.584 INFO  TaskDeployer - Deploying tasks into commands.
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:09.584 TRACE TaskDeployer - Task 'indent' found in >'C:\texlive\2014\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\rules'.
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:09.728 TRACE TaskDeployer - Task 'indent' found in 
>   'C:\texlive\2014\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\rules'.
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:09.738 INFO  CommandTrigger - Ready to run commands.
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:09.738 INFO  CommandTrigger - Running 'Indent'.
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:09.738 TRACE CommandTrigger - Command: cmd /c latexindent.exe 
>   "tikpkzTEST.tex"
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:10.048 TRACE CommandTrigger - Output logging:
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:10.048 TRACE CommandTrigger - % arara: indent
>
> % arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
>
> \documentclass[10pt]{article}
>   \begin{document}
>   \begin{enumerate}
>     \item a
>     \item b
>     \item c
>   \end{enumerate}
>   \end{document}
>   11 Dec 2014 18:50:10.048 INFO  CommandTrigger - 'Indent' was successfully executed.
>   11 Dec 2014 18:50:10.048 INFO  CommandTrigger - Running 'Indent'.
>   11 Dec 2014 18:50:10.048 TRACE CommandTrigger - Command: cmd /c latexindent.exe     -w    >"tikpkzTEST.tex" 
>   11 Dec 2014 18:50:10.348 TRACE CommandTrigger - Output logging:
>   11 Dec 2014 18:50:10.348 TRACE CommandTrigger - % arara: indent
>   % arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
>
> \documentclass[10pt]{article}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \begin{enumerate}
>
> \item a
>
> \item b
>
> \item c
>
> \end{enumerate}
>
> \end{document}
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:10.348 INFO  CommandTrigger - 'Indent' was successfully executed.
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:10.348 INFO  CommandTrigger - All commands were successfully executed.
>
> 11 Dec 2014 18:50:10.348 INFO  Arara - Done.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want with `arara` but you can indent your code using the TeXmaker menu, or not?

Comment: @Sigur `indent` is a nice tool for automatic code indentation (latexindent from cmhughes). I do not think that TeXmaker is able to do such work.

Comment: latexindent is a perl script which can be used via arara. A minimal working example is:% arara: indent
% arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item sahddjhhsv
 \item asdasdfasdf
\end{enumerate}
fcaf dfgdddsaf
\end{document}     Texmaker can not autoindent code, so I was trying this workaround. As said; arara correctly indents the code from the command line, but not from TeXmaker.

Comment: does the editor lock the file for writing? that is while the file is in texmaker can you edit it with _anything_ (eg notepad) if it is locked then the perl script won't be able to edit it.

Comment: No, when the file is opened with TeXmaker, you can still run arara myFile.tex. TexMaker then opens a window reading "the file your are working with has been changed. do you wish to apply those changes?" when clicking "yes" the indentation is visible in TeXmaker.

Comment: There will be `indent.log` file in that directory. What does that say?

Comment: The log file is changed when invoking via TeXmaker. It looks the same (as far as I can tell) if I use the command line. I will append it to the original post.

Comment: Maybe you need to reload the file.

Comment: Reloading does not help. If the tex-file is changed externally TeXmaker notifies it happend. It does not notify when using the arara-command. When closing and reopening after using the arara-command the file is still unchanged and not beautified.

Comment: Any suggestions for an alternative editor, that plays better with arara/latexindent?

Comment: @Björn do you just want to indent the code with texmaker and then run `arara` for automation or do simultaneously  ? could you run  arara with this flags in user command of texmaker `arara %.tex --verbose --log` to know what the arara.log says

Comment: I set texmaker up so that F1 does runs pdflatex and shows the pdf. The command is invoked via ALT+SHIFT+F1 which I want to result in indented code.

Comment: The the arara-log-file seems fine (generated via texmaker). It shows the correct intendation (which does not transfer to texmaker). I will put the .log in the original post under PPPS.

Comment: I hope you have followed these interesting links: [Check External changes in TeXmaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126668/15717) and [Invoking arara from TeXmaker user command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107995/15717)

Comment: I'll install TeXmaker later on and try to reproduce your issue. `:)`

Comment: I suspect `arara` is working, but TeXmaker is not aware of changes in the current file. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: It's nice to see `latexindent.pl` being used :) It's a good sign that it works from the command line. You only need *one* `arara` directive for `latexindent`; in your MWE you have *two* directives--the first doesn't overwrite your source, the second *does*. I'll have a look at this as well--I haven't used TeXmaker before...

Comment: @cmhughes may be TeXmaker checks for external changes based on time stamps of file, I think with texmaker user command `latexindent -w %.tex` Texmaker does not detect the new file changes but `latexident` works fine and file is indented well. IMO `Check for external changes` works only if the file had been modified outside TeXmaker enviroment eg: like a command line interface how Bjorn tried. I don't know if TeXmaker `check for external changes` need to corrected or fool the texmaker by `latexindent` file overwriting process.

Comment: I also tried to get latexindent to work via command-line (embedded in TeXmaker) with the same (non)-result.

Comment: @cmhughes while testing on my windows 8 I receive this error `Can't locate YAML/Tiny.pm in @INC (you may need to install the YAML::Tiny module) (@INC contains:C:/texlive/2014/tlpkg/tlperl/lib c:/texlive/2014/tlpkg/tlperl/lib .) at c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/latexindent.pl line 20.
` when i run at command window `latexindent`, Is there something i am doing wrong ? any workarounds ?

Comment: @texenthusiast you need to use your perl distribution to install yaml::tiny. Once you've done that, all should be good :)

Comment: @cmhughes the error persists even with installing `YAML::Tiny` and other needed modules for latexindent via CPAN in strawberry perl 64 bit win8. `helloworld.pl` runs well. `perl latexindent.pl` works well when run from the TL 2014 scripts directory. for some reason `latexindent.exe` does not work and throws me above error. I think perl need not be installed as perl lib come packaged with TeXLive(may be it misses YAML::Tiny module). so `latexindent.exe` should work right without a strawberry perl installed ?

Comment: My Guess is TeXlive tlperl directory is missing the needed modules for execution of latexindent.exe also see [related thread](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=25096) . It's [fixed in texlive extra pacakges for debian/ubuntu](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=765660) not for vanilla may be. IMO If TeXLive perl has basic restricted modules that only help tlmgr working, then `latexindent.exe` should not try searching for modules in TeXLive `tlperl` folder and it should rather look for strawberry perl path and with proper syncing of perl version modules.

Comment: @cmhughes  So Finally this workaround worked for me. copy entire YAML folder with `Tiny.pm` from C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib to C:\texlive\2014\tlpkg\tlperl\lib and any missing `File:HomeDir` modules from strawberry perl lib (similar version of perl in TeXLive ) to tlperl lib folder then `latexindent.exe` should fine. BTW IMO Bjorn Error of not updating the .tex file after latexindent in usercommand may be an issue pertaining to TeXmaker editor not arara or latexindent. Bjorn may be you post this [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/)

Comment: @texenthusiast thanks for the updates; I certainly agree that the module implementation isn't ideal--I think I need to make `latexindent.pl` choose the appropriate modules from the distribution, not from `tlperl`.

Comment: @Björn workaround: In TeXmaker File menu press `Reload Document from file` to see updated the current file with indented contents. For me latexindent.exe works from commandline and texmaker detects the file changes automatically and it prompts for a option "Document has changed outside of Texmaker do wish to reload the documents with changes have it overwritten etc..". Note you may use `Add Path` in `Options`-->`Configure`  TeXmaker to give texmaker user commands to access any binary paths of strawberry perl. Also you may execute external commands using `Tools` menu -->`Open Terminal`

Comment: thanks everyone for looking into it. The workaround posted by @texenthusiast is working for me. (via latexindent.exe I also have to "Reload Document from file" to make it work). I will post to the issue tracker of TeXmaker about the "no-auto-update if changed via texmaker"-issue and mark this question as answered.

Comment: @texenthusiast I believe that v2.1R of `latexindent` should now work more smoothly on TeXLive for Windows. As you probably know, TL2014 is frozen, but it should be part of TL2015. If you'd like to grab it manually, you can get `latexindent.exe` from `https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl`; by using the standalone executable, there shouldn't be any need to tangle with `perl` distributions.... hopefully

Answer (score 2):

@texenthusiast has found a workaround for the problem:

> In TeXmaker File menu press Reload Document from file to see updated
>   the current file with indented contents.

So basicly you can set up arara/the command-line-version of latexindent to indent the code via TeXmaker:

> (*) (Users->Commands->User-defined "arara %.tex" or "texmaker.exe" -w %.tex) or alternatively via 
>   (Options->quickbuild->...)

A minor inconvenience remains however: You will have to invoke latex-indent via ALT+SHIFT+F1 (as set up in (*)) and then you will additionaly have to choose "reload document" from the file menu. This should be good enough for most users.

Comment: Nice answer, glad you were able to work through it. If you're on Windows, you might also like `TeXnicCenter` or `NotePad++` which reload the file automatically and ask for a simple confirmation from the user :)