# How to configure TexLive 2015 to use latexindent.pl script with Kile

Tags: texlive, arara, latexindent

I would like to autoindent my code under Kile using `latexindent`.
I have TeXLive 2015 installed and I run `arara` on my tex file.

I tried to follow the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexindent/documentation/manual.pdf) instructions (p.5)  for [latexindent](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent) where it is said to copy `indent.yaml` to the directory of `arara` rules or to add the directory in which `latexindent.pl` resides to my araraconfig.yaml file. This last one doesn't exist in my TeXLive distribution nor the `indent.yaml` file, so I copied `ident.yaml` to `arara` rules directory but I get this error message:

> I'm sorry, but the command from the 'Indent' task could not be found.
> Are you sure the command 'latexindent.pl -s -t -w "filename.tex" is
> correct, or even accessible from the system path?

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm finally able to run [indentlatex](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl) correctly and here is how I solved the problem

First one have to create a configuration file for arara:  `araraconfig.yaml`. This file should be placed in your home directory `/home/<yourusername>` and should indicate the path of `latexindent.pl` file in your system. My `araraconfig.yaml` on my Linux machine looks like this:

```
config
paths:
- /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent
```

(The `latexindent` script comes with the 2015 TeX Live distribution).

Then one should copy `indent.yaml` in the `arara` rules directory (to be downloaded from [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent)). 
At this stage it is still not possible to run `latexindent`, some modules must be installed (see [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexindent/documentation/manual.pdf) p. 17). For this, from the command line run:

```
cpan
```

If not installed, Linux will ask you to install it.
Then from the CPAN prompt you could install missing moudules:

```
install YAML::Tiny
install Getopt::Long
install File::HomeDir
```

Once installation is finished, you can run `latexindent` from the command line:

```
latexindent
```

and to make it possible to run with arara, one last thing is needed, you should remove the .pl from the `indent.yaml` file. Here is the line that should be modified

> command:  @{ isWindows( "cmd /c latexindent.exe",
>   "latexindent.pl" ) } @{silent} @{trace} @{localSettings} @{cruft}@{
>   isNotEmpty( cruft, '="'.concat(parameters.cruft).concat('"') ) }
>   @{overwrite}  @{onlyDefault} @{output} "@{file}" @{ isNotEmpty(
>   output, '"'.concat(parameters.output).concat('"') ) }

Comment: Awesome, great work +1 from me :) I'll delete my answer :)