# In Texmaker how does one turn off auto indent on newline?

Tags: texmaker

I've googled my heart out and I can't seem to find an answer.

The default behaviour in Texmaker (GNU/Linux) is when you hit enter, it will carry over your tabs, such as tabbing like this:

```
|
|
    |
    |
        |
        |
```

Is there anyway to turn off this auto-indent when hitting enter. In vim it's: `set noautoindent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such option in Texmaker.

You can:

1. use an external program to autoindent the code, see [Autoindent in Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126241/autoindent-in-texmaker) which will [hopefully] correct the indentation for you or
2. switch to [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net), a fork of Texmaker, which has this option in the [editor configuration](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION01): Menu > Options > Configure TeXstudio > Editor > [Indentation mode] select `Ignore Indentation` from the drop down.

Comment: That's disappointing. Odd you can't turn off a very common option. Thank you for the help.