# texstudio indent based on the levels

Tags: texstudio

Is it possible to indent in texstudio based on the levels?
It seems that a proper macro might be able to do such a job, though it seems to be complicated.

Edit:

Thanks to Troy, we know that latexindent has this capacity.Therefore the problem is to write a macro which runs the latexindent on all file at once without causing problems.

Comment: [`latexindent`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent?lang=en) does this. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351020/117534

Comment: You don't need a macro for this. Just set it up with a custom user command as suggested by the link above. What OS are you using?